# Behaviors of stack pointer in ARM64

Tags: assembly, arm64, memory-alignment, stack-memory, abi

Because of a lack of PUSH and POP instructions in ARM64, I'm having a problem with understanding how SP work in ARM64.

If I were to PUSH/POP, does the SP decrement/increment by 4, 8 or 16 bytes?

I'm reading documentations saying that the stack frame must be aligned by 16 bytes, but when I debug, it doesn't seemed to be the case exactly.

Comment: Short answer, you do push and pop register values with standard load/store instructions or just "add" or "subtract" from the stack pointer to align or make room for larger allocations.  Most instructions can be run against the SP without issue (IP as well, but usually with a small perf penalty.)

Comment: I confirm I am able to set the SP to unusable values and can still step thru each instruction without problem using lldb.

Here is my code:<br>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {<br>
    asm volatile("mov sp, 1");
    asm volatile("mov sp, 2");
    asm volatile("mov sp, 3");
    return 0;
}

The crash that does happen is after the return statement. Looks like a library function tried to access memory at the bad address.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whether the stack grows upwards or downwards is entirely dependent on the ABI of the system you're looking at. That said, all arm64 code I've had to do with had downwards-growing stacks.
With that, a common push would look like this:

```
stp x29, x30, [sp, -0x10]!
```

And a common pop like this:

```
ldp x29, x30, [sp], 0x10
```

This obviously pushes/pops two registers at once and thus modifies the stack pointer by 16 bytes at a time, which brings us to the next part:

The stack alignment check. Whether or not the stack pointer must be aligned to a 16-byte boundary is *also* dependent on the ABI you're working with, but is an actual hardware feature that can be configured.
See [the ARMv8 Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest), `SCTLR_EL[123]` include bits that turn this feature on or off for each exception level. Quote from `SCTLR_EL1`, for example:

```
SA0, bit [4]

    SP Alignment check enable for EL0. When set to 1, if a load or store
    instruction executed at EL0 uses the SP as the base address and the SP is not
    aligned to a 16-byte boundary, then a SP alignment fault exception is
    generated. For more information, see SP alignment checking on page D1-2333.

    When ARMv8.1-VHE is implemented, and the value of HCR_EL2.{E2H, TGE} is
    {1, 1}, this bit has no effect on execution at EL0.

    In a system where the PE resets into EL1, this field resets to an
    architecturally UNKNOWN value.

SA, bit [3]

    SP Alignment check enable. When set to 1, if a load or store instruction
    executed at EL1 uses the SP as the base address and the SP is not aligned to
     a 16-byte boundary, then a SP alignment fault exception is generated. For
    more information, see SP alignment checking on page D1-2333.

    When ARMv8.1-VHE is implemented, and the value of HCR_EL2.{E2H, TGE} is
    {1, 1}, this bit has no effect on the PE.

    In a system where the PE resets into EL1, this field resets to an
    architecturally UNKNOWN value.
```