# I need general tips and guidance on converting this C code to assembly for AArch64 macOS (M1)

Tags: macos, assembly, arm64

I know that you can use the GCC option to convert this to assembly but that did not teach me anything about the process.  Are there guides out there on how to do this?  I am on MacOS.  My professor did not say anything about the difference of coding assembly on Windows vs. MacOS or anything.

```
int main()
{
    int x, y, result=0;

    //read x
    printf("Please enter x: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    //read y
    printf("Please enter y: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    if (y<0)
    {
            x=0-x;
            y=0-y;
     }

    for (int counter=0; counter<y; counter++)
    {
        result+=x;
    }
    printf("x*y =  %d\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my best attempt so far:

```
.section .data
input_x_prompt: .asciz "Please enter x: "
input_y_prompt: .asciz "Please enter y: "
input_spec: .asciz "%d"
result_prompt: .asciz "x*y = %d\n"

.section .bss
x: .space 4
y: .space 4
result: .space 4

.section .text
.global main

main:
    # Display "Please enter x: "
    ldr x0, =input_x_prompt
    bl printf
    
    # Read x
    ldr x0, =x
    ldr x1, =input_spec
    bl scanf

    # Display "Please enter y: "
    ldr x0, =input_y_prompt
    bl printf

    # Read y
    ldr x0, =y
    ldr x1, =input_spec
    bl scanf

    # Check if y is negative and negate both x and y
    ldr x1, [y]
    cmp x1, 0
    blt negate_x_and_y

calculate_product:
    # Initialize result to 0
    mov x2, 0

    # Initialize counter to 0
    mov x3, 0

product_loop:
    # Compare counter with y
    cmp x3, x1
    bge print_result

    # Add x to the result
    ldr x4, [x]
    add x2, x2, x4

    # Increment counter
    add x3, x3, 1

    # Repeat the loop
    b product_loop

print_result:
    # Display the result
    ldr x0, =result_prompt
    ldr x1, [x2]
    bl printf

exit:
    mov x0, 0
    mov x8, 93
    svc 0
    ret

negate_x_and_y:
    # Negate x
    ldr x4, [x]
    neg x4, x4
    str x4, [x]

    # Negate y
    ldr x4, [y]
    neg x4, x4
    str x4, [y]
    b calculate_product
```

Please see above for my attempted code.

Comment: You've repeatedly ignored the first code block in [Accessing global variables in ARM64 position independent assembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75474024) which shows how to access global variables using `adrp` plus `add` or with a the low bits of the displacement as part of the addressing mode.  Or just look at compiler output for a working example.  https://godbolt.org/z/7nen6M1nY shows `clang -O1 -target aarch64-apple-darwin` output which I think is correct for how to call functions etc.  You might want to un-optimize it more to turn the `mul` back into a loop, or perhaps use `-Og`.

Comment: I may ask you more questions in the future, but the first code block with the global variables was given to us by the professor who told us that it was skeleton code we could use.  So I'm a bit confused as to how it's a problem here?

Comment: I think `scanf` needs the format string as first parameters.

Comment: Your `.data` and `.bss` sections are fine for using scanf and printf. It's how you access them that's the problem, not how you define them. e.g. `ldr x4, [x]` can't work; I don't think AArch64 even has an addressing mode that's `xzr + 12-bit immediate` that could encode `[x]` even if the address was in the bottom 16KiB of virtual address-space.  You keep randomly trying stuff that isn't `adrp` into a temp register and then `ldr reg, [reg, x@PAGEOFF]`

Answer (score 1):

Alright, let's fix your assembly step by step.

Let's first get it to compile. Throwing it at `cc` as-is gives us this:

```
t.s:1:15: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
.section .data
              ^
t.s:7:14: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
.section .bss
             ^
t.s:12:15: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
.section .text
              ^
t.s:35:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
    ldr x1, [y]
             ^
t.s:52:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
    ldr x4, [x]
             ^
t.s:75:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
    ldr x4, [x]
             ^
t.s:77:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
    str x4, [x]
             ^
t.s:80:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
    ldr x4, [y]
             ^
t.s:82:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
    str x4, [y]
```

These are really just two kinds of errors, each repeated a few times:

1. Section directives. `.section .data` is invalid. You either write `.data`, or `.section __DATA,__data`. Same goes for `.text` (`__TEXT,__text`) and `.bss` (`__DATA,__bss`). A complete list of section aliases can be found by searching for `DarwinAsmParser::parseSectionDirective` in [`llvm/lib/MC/MCParser/DarwinAsmParser.cpp` in the LLVM source tree](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/MC/MCParser/DarwinAsmParser.cpp).
2. Accessing global variables with `[]`. That's not how it works. `[]` is for dereferencing registers. The instruction set allows PC-relative loads from like `ldr x1, y`, but the macOS toolchain only allows that if the label loaded from is in the same section as the instruction doing the load. Since the labels `x` and `y` that you load from are in data, you can't use that here. But that would've only allowed you to do loads anyway, but you also wanna do stores, so you need to generate the address of the label either way. You can do that by generating the 4K page of the label with `adrp xN, label@PAGE`, and then either using `add xN, xN, label@PAGEOFF`, or by inserting `label@PAGEOFF` directly into the `ldr`/`str` instructions:

   ```
   adrp x1, y@PAGE
   ldr x1, [x1, y@PAGEOFF]
   ```

   ```
   adrp x5, x@PAGE
   ldr x4, [x5, x@PAGEOFF]
   neg x4, x4
   str x4, [x5, x@PAGEOFF]
   ```

Once that's fixed, we get some linker errors:

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _main, referenced from:
      <initial-undefines>
  printf, referenced from:
      main in t-15d51f.o
      main in t-15d51f.o
      main in t-15d51f.o
  scanf, referenced from:
      main in t-15d51f.o
      main in t-15d51f.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The first error already hints at the solution: assembly names of C functions need to be prefixed with an underscore on Darwin, so `_main`, `_printf` and `_scanf`.

Once that's fixed up, we get a new linker error:

```
ld: 'y' from '/private/var/folders/0s/mrkxlvcs10l0tswpv763_fdw0000gn/T/t-262b4d.o' not 8-byte aligned, which cannot be encoded as a target of LDR/STR in '_main' from '/private/var/folders/0s/mrkxlvcs10l0tswpv763_fdw0000gn/T/t-262b4d.o'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

These are actually two errors in one.
First, the labels *are* not aligned to anything. And because `ldr` and `str` store their offset scaled by the size of the loaded value, 8-byte loads can only load from 8-byte aligned addresses. We can fix that by putting `.balign 8` between `.bss` and `x:`.
But second, 8 bytes isn't right! We only have `.space 4` for our global variables. So we actually need to adjust the assembly to use `w1`, `w4`, etc. instead of `x1`, `x4`, etc. And then we should use `.balign 4`.

With that fixed, it compiles now. But it doesn't work yet, we immediately get a segmentation fault. That is because `ldr xN, =...` doesn't work on Darwin, due to codesigning. See [How to load data by label on Apple Silicon (ARM64)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76318308).
Once you're done fixing that, the only remaining `=` in your code should be inside a string.

But the code still crashes. And at this point it's time to look at some compiler output.
I have taken your C code above and moved `int x, y, result=0;` outside of `main()` to match what the assembly is doing, and also given it the `volatile` modifier to prevent the compiler from optimising out any access.
Compiling it with `-S -O3`, and then stripping away some `.loh` and `.cfi*` directives as well as some auto-generated comments leaves us with this:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 14, 0 sdk_version 14, 0
    .globl  _main
    .p2align    2
_main:
    sub sp, sp, #64
    stp x22, x21, [sp, #16]
    stp x20, x19, [sp, #32]
    stp x29, x30, [sp, #48]
    add x29, sp, #48
    adrp    x0, l_.str@PAGE
    add x0, x0, l_.str@PAGEOFF
    bl  _printf
    adrp    x20, _x@GOTPAGE
    ldr x20, [x20, _x@GOTPAGEOFF]
    str x20, [sp]
    adrp    x19, l_.str.1@PAGE
    add x19, x19, l_.str.1@PAGEOFF
    mov x0, x19
    bl  _scanf
    adrp    x0, l_.str.2@PAGE
    add x0, x0, l_.str.2@PAGEOFF
    bl  _printf
    adrp    x21, _y@GOTPAGE
    ldr x21, [x21, _y@GOTPAGEOFF]
    str x21, [sp]
    mov x0, x19
    bl  _scanf
    ldr w8, [x21]
    tbnz    w8, #31, LBB0_2
    ldr w9, [x21]
    adrp    x8, _result@PAGE
    cmp w9, #1
    b.ge    LBB0_3
    b   LBB0_5
LBB0_2:
    ldr w8, [x20]
    neg w8, w8
    str w8, [x20]
    ldr w8, [x21]
    neg w8, w8
    str w8, [x21]
    ldr w9, [x21]
    adrp    x8, _result@PAGE
    cmp w9, #1
    b.lt    LBB0_5
LBB0_3:
    mov w9, #0
LBB0_4:
    ldr w10, [x20]
    ldr w11, [x8, _result@PAGEOFF]
    add w10, w11, w10
    str w10, [x8, _result@PAGEOFF]
    add w9, w9, #1
    ldr w10, [x21]
    cmp w9, w10
    b.lt    LBB0_4
LBB0_5:
    ldr w8, [x8, _result@PAGEOFF]
    str x8, [sp]
    adrp    x0, l_.str.3@PAGE
    add x0, x0, l_.str.3@PAGEOFF
    bl  _printf
    mov w0, #0
    ldp x29, x30, [sp, #48]
    ldp x20, x19, [sp, #32]
    ldp x22, x21, [sp, #16]
    add sp, sp, #64
    ret

    .globl  _result
.zerofill __DATA,__common,_result,4,2
    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
l_.str:
    .asciz  "Please enter x: "
l_.str.1:
    .asciz  "%d"
    .comm   _x,4,2
l_.str.2:
    .asciz  "Please enter y: "
    .comm   _y,4,2
l_.str.3:
    .asciz  "x*y =  %d\n"

.subsections_via_symbols
```

One thing that you'll notice is that this uses the stack. Not just to set up a stack frame, not just to spill registers, but it actively writes things to the stack before certain function calls. Specifically: *varargs*. The prototypes of `printf` and `scanf` are as follows:

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
int scanf(const char *restrict format, ...);
```

The exact ABI has a bunch of edge cases ([see here for a more comprehensive answer on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69455440)), but in this case it's sufficient to say that named arguments go in registers, while varargs go on the stack, each padded to 8 bytes.
So your format strings go in `x0`, and the pointers for scanf and the integer for printf go to `[sp]`... which also means you need to reserve some stack space. Adding `sub sp, sp, 0x10` at the beginning of `_main` is sufficient, you just [need to make sure that the stack is always aligned to 16 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63003387).
In `print_result` you also have `ldr x1, [x2]`, which... I have no idea where that's coming from? `x2` already is the integer result, so I replaced that with `str w2, [sp]`.

Fixing all of that makes the code actually work:

```
Please enter x: 7
Please enter y: 8
x*y = 56
zsh: invalid system call  ./t
```

...but it still crashes at the very end. That's because you're using the syscall ABI for Linux. For more details on the (unstable!) arm64 XNU syscall ABI, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56993314), but it's sufficient to say here that the syscall number goes in `x16` and the syscall number for `exit` is 1:

```
exit:
    mov x0, 0
    mov x16, 1
    svc 0
```

And with that, it exits cleanly.

Comment: A raw `_exit` system call isn't recommended when using stdio `printf`.  You should either call `fflush(NULL)` first, or better call the libc `exit` function which will flush buffers.  stdout is line buffered on the terminal, but full-buffered with `./t  > outfile.txt < test_input.txt` or a pipe like a grading program might use for automated testing.  In that case `printf("...\n", ...);`  `svc`/x16=0 would produce no output.

Comment: @Power555 You seem to be putting apostrophes and/or backticks in your code.